# Non-consumable Free trial

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

in-app-purchase using Non-consumable how to add add free trial period, do I have to make the price 0? there is no documentation how to make free trial for Non-consumable option.
I was thinking that configuring the price in apple developer account in-app-purchase and from device enable all options for 2 weeks then ask for the payment, do you think this can work with guideline?
[image]

Just another question, I added the price, but when user start to download it doesn't ask to pay before downloading right? I have to implement a button with storkit to ask a payment inside my app when free trial finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introductory offers such as free trials are not available for non-consumables products. Only auto-renewable subscriptions can have introductory offers. More info here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/implementing_introductory_offers_in_your_app

Answer (score 4):

This is not true (or at least isn’t true anymore). Quoting from Apple’s “App Store Review Guidelines”
“

> Non-subscription apps may offer a free time-based trial period before presenting a full unlock option by setting up a Non-Consumable IAP item at Price Tier 0 that follows the naming convention: “XX-day Trial.” Prior to the start of the trial, your app must clearly identify its duration, the content or services that will no longer be accessible when the trial ends, and any downstream charges the user would need to pay for full functionality.

The full text is available here: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase